# Python private instance data revisited

Tags: javascript, python, perl, closures, private

I've read various "there is no truly private data in Python instances" posts, but we're all aware of using closures in Perl and JavaScript to effectively achieve private data.  So why not in Python?

For example:

```
import codecs

class Secret:
    def __private():
        secret_data = None

        def __init__(self, string):
            nonlocal secret_data
            if secret_data is None:
                secret_data = string
        
        def getSecret(self):
            return codecs.encode(secret_data, 'rot_13')

        return __init__, getSecret

    __init__, getSecret = __private()
```

Now we do:

```
>>> thing = Secret("gibberish")
>>> thing.getSecret()
'tvoorevfu'
>>> dir(thing)
['_Secret__private', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'getSecret']
```

What can you do to the instance *thing* to get read access to the original string (ignoring my weak encryption) or write access to it?

I'm teaching my students about Python classes this week and I'm trying to understand why, given closures, the techniques for JavaScript & Perl won't work for Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to *access* the original, it's not that hard, since Python function implement a rather thorough inspection api. You can access the original secret with something like this:

```
thing = Secret("gibberish")
# __init__ doesn't need to be used here; anything defined within the closure will do
thing.__init__.__func__.__closure__[0].cell_contents
```

And, hey! We get the original value.

It is harder---but not impossible---to modify the value (see [here](https://dzone.com/articles/nothing-private-python)). Modified for this setup:

```
import ctypes
...

thing = Secret("gibberish")
cell = ctypes.py_object(thing.__init__.__func__.__closure__[0])
new_value = ctypes.py_object('whatever')
ctypes.pythonapi.PyCell_Set(cell, new_value)

thing.getSecret()
```

Comment: Thank you @ig0774, I've fixed __init__ to no longer be a setter after the fact.  Your link doesn't seem to lead somewhere apropos of this discussion.  I'm glad to see Python living up to it's, "There's more than one way to do it." motto -- oh wait, never mind.

Comment: @cdlane: somehow the link I intended is not the one that ended up there. I've updated it to the correct link. Basically you have to use the C API, but it's still possible to do.

Comment: @cdlane: See my recent edit which shows how to set the cell value to pretty much any arbitrary Python object.

Comment: If you drop down to C level, can't I counter by moving my data hiding down there as well, only to have you drop below C level to machine code to counter me again.  Both you and mhawke have easily convinced me that there is no read protection and that write protection may be implementation specific.  Perhaps Perl and JavaScript are just a good introspection package away from not being able to rely on data hiding via closures either.  Thank you again.

Comment: I suppose by the standard used here even Java or C# don't "really" have private data since you can use reflection or drop to IL to overwrite just about anything, but both those languages' standard environments provide means of controlling that level of access (via code signing etc.). I think the broader point is that the Python interpreter makes no effort to hide any executing code and, in fact, goes out of its way to expose a lot of information about what the interpreter is doing.

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't ordinarily do this but you can dig into the instance with module `inspect`.

```
>>> thing = Secret("gibberish")
>>> thing.getSecret()
'tvoorevfu'
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getclosurevars(thing.getSecret).nonlocals['secret_data']
'gibberish'
>>> inspect.getclosurevars(thing.__init__).nonlocals['secret_data']
'gibberish'
```

Given one of the functions within the closure, you can access the closure's variables. I haven't yet found a way to modify the variable.

So it's not impossible if you are willing to go to some effort. Why you would do that in the normal course of programming I don't know.

Comment: Thank you @mhawke, I used the inspect module to harden my original example but feared that some wizard would still use it to break in.